# How do I know what GPS provider is using

Tags: ios, gps, location, cllocationmanager

I developing iOS application working with user location. The question is

"I would like to know that current location is come from Wifi or 3g or else? I would like to know the provider."

Is this possible? I googled around with no luck.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can't know *how* it is getting it, but you can know the accuracy of the locations you receive.  Every `CLLocation` object has a `horizontalAccuracy` property that you can check.  It will indicate the margin of error in meters.  Also it has a `verticalAccuracy` property for 3D locations.

Comment: You can now how it is detected, by having background knowledge. Only GPS delivers course and speed. No other locationing system used in smartphones,

Comment: You can "deduce" it maybe, but that is based on indirect knowledge.  The only information available via API is this.

Comment: There was a Post on Apple forum of one Apple developper that explained the senesors used in the different accuracy modes. It is available here on So, too. But from API view, you cannot.

Answer (score 1):

First if the device has GPS and you choose CLLLocationAcuracyBest or BestForNavigation, then GPS is used as Location provider all the time.

If you dont want to use that modes, you can distuniguish the location Provider by:

Only GPS delivers the attributes "course/heading" and "speed". 
No other (WLAN, GSM-cell) can provice course and speed.

Altitude theoretically could be provided by GSM-Cell (or Wlan), so it could be unsafe to use the altitude as GPS identification hint. I do not recomend using altitude.

While standing still course will also be invalid even when using GPS, while speed will be a valid 0.

A further very good working solution is to use the horicontal accuracy < 40 condition.

GSM Cell will  have hor. accuracy much higher than 40m, eg. 1000m.

- if you have horicontal accuracy < 30 its for sure form GPS
- if you have a valid course: Its for sure from GPS
- if you have a valid speed: Its for sure from GPS

In all other cases its a bad position, and it usually is not necarry for further finding wheter from bad GPS or good Wlan / GSM

Answer (score 0):

I ran in to the same problem like you few months ago.
I found some similar questions on stackoverflow that have the same answers like:

your device will automatically send updated location information to your app wherether it from GPS, wifi, EDGE, 3G ...

depends on your code when you init your `CLLocationManager`